# How to dynamically import json data using Svelte

Tags: javascript, json, svelte

I have previously been testing a component using the following code

```
<script>
import x from "/path/to/x.json"
</script>
```

this, as expected loads the `json` file to variable `x`.

What I would like to do, is **dynamically load a local json file given an `<input>` element** e.g.

```
<script>
let files ;
function loadJSONFile(){
  doSomething(files[0].name) ;
}
</script>

<input type="file" bind:files on:change={loadJSONFile}>
```

where `doSomething()` is doing the equivalent task of `import` in the first example.

Ideally, I could load the data from any local folder, so `bind:files` may not be appropriate, as `files[0].name` seems to yield a relative path, rather than an absolute path.

Comment: What do you mean by "local folder"? Local to the application or the user?

Comment: Local to the user @H.B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read a user-provided file, you can use the `FileReader` API. The best place to do that would be the change event.

(If the user cancels the dialog, the files will be cleared.)

```html
<script>
    let json;
    
    async function onChange(e) {
        const file = e.target.files[0];
        if (file == null) {
            json = null;
            return;
        }
        
        json = await readJsonFile(file);
    }

    function readJsonFile(file) {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            reader.onload = () => resolve(JSON.parse(reader.result));
            reader.onerror = reject;
            reader.readAsText(file);
        });
    }
</script>

<input type=file on:change={onChange} accept=".json"/>
<pre>{JSON.stringify(json, null, '  ')}</pre>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/057641484590488296582bf5317b1aa4?version=3.50.1)

Comment: This answered my question exactly, thank you.